# Centered icon and text in div

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm playing around with a tutorial I've found where an icon is displayed next to some text in a list. (http://praveenfrancis.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-menu-with-css-sprite/)

What I'd like to do is try and make the icon and text centered in the `<li>` so that when the menu is made fluid and resized, the text and icon remain in the center of the element.

I've created a jsfiddle and tried to do it but I can't seem to get things quite right. Can anyone give me some pointers?

http://jsfiddle.net/PuZwb/

Comment: May have to use some more elements for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/PuZwb/2/. You need to enclose the sprite in an element or in a pseudoselector like `:before` and then use `display: inline-block` and then `vertical-align: middle`.

## CSS

```
ul.menu li:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:url("http://chrisandjennyswedding.com/sprite.png") no-repeat;
}

ul.menu li#cakes:before   {background-position:0 0}
ul.menu li#donuts:before  {background-position:0 -64px}
ul.menu li#rolls:before   {background-position:0 -128px}
ul.menu li#pies:before {background-position:0 -196px}
```

Comment: add an extra `text-align: center` if you want also horizontal alignment: http://jsfiddle.net/PuZwb/4/

Comment: Lovely use of the selector. Just what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To do it your way you would have to add a width to the `<li>`. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PuZwb/3/) to see what I mean.

This would also be a great place to use the `:before` pseudo selector.

Comment: Very nice solution with minimal changes.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your your ul in a div like

```
body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="cakes">cakes</li>
        <li id="donuts">donuts</li>
        <li id="rolls">rolls</li>
        <li id="pies">pies</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then css like this

```
.menu {
width: 210px;
background-color: #09C; 
margin 0 auto;

}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #09C;
```

this will center your ul nice and simple